# Do I have to lock a CVPixelBuffer produced from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-video, cvpixelbuffer

I have a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` producing `CMSampleBuffer` instances passed into my `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` function. I want to efficiently convert the pixel buffers into `CGImage` instances for usage elsewhere in my app.

I have to be careful not to retain any references to these pixel buffers or the capture session will start dropping frames for reason `OutOfBuffers`. Also, if the conversion takes too long then then frames will be discarded for reason `FrameWasLate`.

Previously I tried using a `CIContext` to render the `CGImage` but this proved to be too slow when capturing above 30 FPS, and I want to capture at 60 FPS. I tested and got up to 38 FPS before frames started getting dropped.

Now I am attempting to use a `CGContext` and the results are better. I'm still dropping frames, but significantly less frequently.

```
public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    // Capture at 60 FPS but only process at 4 FPS, ignoring all other frames
    let timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
    guard timestamp - lastTimestamp >= CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 4) else { return }

    // Extract pixel buffer
    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }

    // Lock pixel buffer before accessing base address
    guard kCVReturnSuccess == CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, .readOnly) else { return }
    defer { CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, .readOnly) }

    // Use CGContext to render CGImage from pixel buffer
    guard let cgimage = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer),
                                  width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                  height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer),
                                  bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                  bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer),
                                  space: cgColorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: cgBitmapInfo).makeImage() else { return }

    // Do something with cgimage...
}
```

I was curious and next tried this without locking the pixel buffer base address. **When I comment out those two lines, I stop dropping frames completely without any noticeable repercussions.** It seems that the lock mechanism was taking so long that frames were being dropped, and removing the mechanism significantly reduced the function's running time and allowed all frames to be handled.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1457115-cvpixelbuffergetbaseaddress) explicitly states that calling `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress` is required prior to `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress`. However, because the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` is using a pre-defined pool of memory for its sample buffers, perhaps the base address isn't subject to change like would normally be the case.

Can I skip locking the base address here? What is the worst that could happen if I don't lock the base address *in this specific scenario*?

Comment: I just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/30947533/1500134 which suggests that locking the pixel buffer is forcing the CPU to get involved, which may be why frames were being dropped. By avoiding the lock, the GPU is used which would certainly explain the speedup. Now I'm left wondering why the docs have been changed and no longer state this.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what are you doing with the `CGImages` afterwards? Why do you need the video frames on the CPU side? It's usually advisable to do as much processing on the GPU as possible.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel we are running them through Core Image filters and passing them to Vision for CoreML inference. We only need them on the CPU at the end if we decide to keep the image (depending on the Vision observations). You are correct, we would rather keep them on the GPU where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was ill-founded from the start because I neglected to test the actual image result from skipping the lock. As stated in the question, when I lock the base address prior to initializing the CGContext, the `makeImage` render would takes approximately 17 milliseconds. If I skip the locking and go straight to the CGContext then the `makeImage` takes 0.3 milliseconds.

I had wrongly interpreted this speed difference to mean that the rendering was being accelerated by the GPU in the latter case. However, what was actually happening was the `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress` was returning `nil` and the `makeImage` was rendering no data- producing a purely white CGImage.

**So, in short, the answer to my question is yes. The base address must be locked.**

Now I am off to figure out how to speed this up. I am capturing at 60 FPS which means I want my rendering to take less than 16 milliseconds if possible so as to drop the CMSampleBuffer reference before the next one arrives.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe you really don't need to convert to `CGImage` at all. You can do all processing within a Core Image + Vision pipeline:

1. Create a `CIImage` from the camera's pixel buffer with `CIImage(cvPixelBuffer:)`.
2. Apply filters to the `CIImage`.
3. Use a `CIContext` to render the filtered image into a new `CVPixelBuffer`. For best performance use a `CVPixelBufferPool` for creating those target pixel buffers.
4. Pass the pixel buffer to Vision for analysis.
5. If Vision decides to keep the image, use the same `CIContext` to render the pixel buffer (wrap it into a `CIImage` again like in 1.) into a target format of your choice, for instance with `context.writeHEIFRepresentation(of:...)`.

Only in the end will the image data be transferred to the CPU side.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try it and see how it compares performance-wise. My only concern is that between steps 1 and 3, we would be keeping a reference to the original pixel buffer, which could cause frame drops for running out of buffers in the allocated memory pool if we aren't processing fast enough. The reason I am currently going through CGImage is to immediately dump that pixel buffer reference before doing anything else.

Comment: This shouldn't be a concern, I think. 1 and 2 basically happen instantly because no rendering is performed until 3. And in 3. the pixel buffer is released as soon as it was used for the rendering. When you'd create copies of the pixel data and can't process it as fast as new buffers arrive you would run out of memory very fast anyways.

Comment: Curiously, rendering the CIImage to a CVPixelBuffer is taking really long- longer than createCGImage. At this speed surely it's still on the CPU- I'm not sure why it isn't using the GPU. createCGImage takes 37ms, render:toCVPixelBuffer takes 46ms with a CVPixelBufferPool and 58ms without. The CGContext.makeImage mechanism in my OP takes 21ms with the base address locked and 0.6ms if I don't lock.

Comment: Did you ask the `AVCaptureDataOutput` to deliver frames in `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`? I would imagine that Core Image is also converting formats when rendering into the `CVPixelBuffer` and that's the reason for the delay. Your `CGContext`-code is super fast because it's basically just re-casting the memory pointer to a `CGImageRef` without any conversion or rendering going on.

Comment: Yes, I did set the output format as kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA. I'm going to close this question because I've technically found the answer- but I might post a followup question for further performance discussion because I'm still struggling to get the render/copy times I would like. Thanks for your help, your suggestion was very insightful!